# Properties of system of two equations and two variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider a system of two equations $f_1(x,y)=0$ and $f_2(x,y)=0$ (that can be nonlinear) with two variables. (it can also be considered in the form of $y=f_1(x)$ and $y=f_2(x)$). Assume that the answer for the system is $(x*,y*)$.

Then, consider another system of equations in which the second equation is replaced with a new equation $f_3(x,y)=0$. If we cannot solve the second system, how can we extract some information about its answer? In particular, I want to know whether the answer for  $x$ and $y$ is higher or lower than $x*$ and $y*$. For example, can the different properties of $f_2$ and $f_3$ (e.g., derivation) help?

Comment: Hi Reza , what do you call an optimal answer ?

Comment: @EDX Thank you so much for your comment. I corrected it. It is actually a feasible answer the satisfies both equations. Thank again!

Comment: For example you can inject directly the solution $(x*,y*)$ of the first system into the third equation and see if it is satisfied. The more equation you add the more **constraints** you will put on your system and the more restrictive the solutions will be.

Comment: @EDX OK. Let's assume that from the first system of equations, we have $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ (or $f_1(x)-f_2(x)=0$); its root is $x_1$. Similarly, from the second system, we have $f_1(x)-f_3(x)=0$; its root is $x_2$. I want to know under what condition(s) $x_1$ is larger or smaller than $x_2$. Is there any way to examine this?